# Node.js REST with Express not responding

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I am new to Node and Express so my knowledge so far is limited. I have a setup with Node.js, Express and MongoDB. I am trying to route the request "localhost:3000/v1/user" by doing like this in my main .js-file:

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:", err);
        } else {
          //HURRAY!! We are connected. :)
          console.log("Connection established to Mongo DB with connection string " + connection_string);


          let port = process.env.NODE_PORT || 3000;
          app.listen(port);
          console.log('Server is now listening to port ' + port);

          app.use(function(req, res){
            req.db = db;
            console.log("DB now available for all routes");
          });


          console.log("Using v1");
          app.use('/v1', v1Route);
        }
      });
```

The connection to mongo gets established OK.
I have two routers in two separate files like this:

v1Route:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();

const userRoute = require('./userRoute');

router.use('/user', userRoute);

module.exports = router;
```

userRoute:

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req,res){
  console.log('fetching all users');
  var collection = req.db.collection('user');
  collection.find().toArray(function (err, result) {

     if (err) {
       console.log(err);
     } else if (result.length > 0) {
       console.log('Found entry');
       res.status(200).send('Found:' + result[0].firstName + ' ' + result[0].lastName).end();
     } else {
       console.log('No document(s) found with defined "find" criteria!');
       res.status(200).send('No document(s) found with defined "find" criteria!').end();
     }
   })


});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem is that nothing happens when I try to make the request "localhost:3000/v1/user". I get no error, just a browser that halts. When I send the request I get the log string "DB now available for all routes".

Comment: Can you call `app.use` before listening on the port?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your middleware function you're not calling `next` handler, so next middleware is not executed:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   req.db = db;
   console.log("DB now available for all routes");
   next();
});
```

You can check more documentation regarding writing middlewares on official `express` website: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

you must launch the server after app.use('/v1', v1Route);

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:", err);
        } else {
          //HURRAY!! We are connected. :)
          console.log("Connection established to Mongo DB with connection string " + connection_string);

          app.use(function(req, res){
            req.db = db;
            console.log("DB now available for all routes");
          });


          console.log("Using v1");
          app.use('/v1', v1Route);

          let port = process.env.NODE_PORT || 3000;
          app.listen(port);
          console.log('Server is now listening to port ' + port);
        }
      });
```